# I am trying to read a txt file and read column one to get column two

Tags: c#, arrays, text-files, streamreader

I have a txt file that will have two different values, all numbers, where the first column is like 00 to 0000000 (2 to 12 in length) and where the second column will be 0120 to 0111111111 like in length (4 to 12 in length). My problems are multiple:

1. How to find the specific value (like a Boolean search)
2. How to return the corresponding value to it's own string

I have toyed with `StreamReader` unsuccessfully (not even able to make any of it work), and I have found such things as `.Split`, `.Parse`, and tried many examples on here and the net that were not actually doing what I needed.

```
/* Example of useless code I found */
class ReadFromFile
{
    static void Main()
    {
        char[] delimiterChars = { ' ', ',', '.', ':', '\t' };

        string text = "one\ttwo three:four,five six seven";
        System.Console.WriteLine($"Original text: '{text}'");

        string[] words = text.Split(delimiterChars);
        System.Console.WriteLine($"{words.Length} words in text:");

        foreach (var word in words)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine($"{word}");
        }
    }
}
```

Well that code was pretty useless, it in no way achieved the mission as it just uses the .Split function to make new rows and not help with finding what was after a specific value.

So specifically I want to search for x value and get y value saved as z value string (using math terms for this portion except the word string).

Comment: you can still split your lines, and store the results in a Dictionary or in List<Tuple<string, string>>. After that, you should be able to extract whatever data you need.

Comment: What is the Delimeter/Separator between the Columns?

Comment: maybe you want to use Regex for your problem. take a look at Regex.Match

Comment: `So specifically I want to search for x value and get y value saved as z value string (using math terms for this portion except the word string)` This is not clear at all, and the demo data you provide  (`"one\ttwo three:four,five six seven"`) does not clarify this any further. Please elaborate on what you want to have happen with clear examples.

Comment: Delimiter is open to anything, I use tabs currently but it can be anything. Abtione any example stuff?

Comment: Flater, I was showing an example of code that I found that was no where near what I needed, I am so lost I hardly know how to ask the question of what functions to use.

Comment: An example of expected input and output would really help.. are you trying to say if column one contains "three" (not numeric?) you get the third character (or word?) from the second column (and the columns are delimited by \t in your example)? Splitting the string into words could be done better but it doesn't seem to be your problem as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although you don't specify it, I presume your file will have multiple lines, each matching your description, like this:

```
00 0120
0000 0111111111 
(etc.)
```

So you need to read each line, parse it using `.Split` and look for the value you want. If you only need to do it once, best would be to check each line immediately after you read it, using StreamReader as in the [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-read-text-from-a-file):

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        char[] delimiterChars = { ' ', ',', '.', ':', '\t' };
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(@"d:\temp\TestFile.txt"))
        {
            string line = sr.ReadLine();
            string[] words = line.Split(delimiterChars);
            if (words[0] == "00")
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Found it, yay!  words[0]={words[0]}, words[1]={words[1]}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to search more than once, instead of searching you could put the split words in some data structure - maybe a `Dictionary` - and search it later as many times as you want.

Comment: The closest one was indeed this one but it seems to have issues with it not being on the top line, where it just will not search additional lines. However this is probable enough for me to continue working with

Answer (score 0):

Like this?:

```
 char[] delimiterChars = { ' ', ',', '.', ':', '\t' };
        string text = "one\ttwo three:four,five six seven";

        string[] words =  text.Split(delimiterChars);
        List<string> values = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i+=2)
        {
            if(words.Length > i)
            if (words[i].Length >= 2 && words[i].Length <= 12) {
                if (words[i+1].Length >= 4 && words[i+1].Length <= 12)
                {
                    values.Add(words[i+1]);
                }
            }
        }
```

I'm really not sure if I understood your question at all :P

(Just comment if I'm way of, and I'll delete the answer again)

Comment: yeah this is what failed to even come close to what I needed, which is why I was like, this is bad code :P

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:**

Please check my code at https://dotnetfiddle.net/txr4Qz and see if it helps you.

**For your problem 1:** How to find the specific value (like a Boolean search)

> You have to check if the word is of a specific type. for eg:

```
// Checks if word is of number (change it as per your requirement)
if (int.TryParse (words[i], out int _) && int.TryParse (words[i+1], out int _)) { ...Statements... }
```

**For your problem 2:** How to return the corresponding value to it's own string

> You are already getting a string form of data from the file. So store it and process it as required.